# Mobile menu effect expands to desktop view

Tags: reactjs

**Question:**

How can I have the navigation of the mobile menu not affect desktop? When I click on the hamburger button to hide the menu and resize the browser to desktop the navigation disappears. I want to know what I did wrong to better understand my mistake.

[GIF Video](https://gyazo.com/e2515634c634c9c3cb616031c69ccfdf)

Full Code Below:

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          show: false
        }
        this.toggleShow = this.toggleShow.bind(this)
        this.hide = this.hide.bind(this)
      }

      toggleShow() {
        this.setState({
          show: !this.state.show
        });
      }

      hide(e) {
        if (e && e.relatedTarget) {
            e.relatedTarget.click();
        }
    }


    render() {
      return (
          <Router>
              <div className="FlexContainer NavbarContainer">
                  <div className="mobilecontainer LeftNav">
                      <h2 className="BrandName LeftNav mobileboxmenu inline FarRight">Kommonplaces</h2>
                      <div 
                      className="hamburger inlinev"  
                      onClick={this.toggleShow}  
                      onBlur={this.hide}>
                          <img alt="menubtn" src={hamburger}></img>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  {
                        this.state.show &&
                    ( 
                        <ul className="NavBar">
                            <Dropdown/>    
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Host Your Space</Link></li>
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">About Us</Link></li>
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Contact Us</Link></li>
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Sign Up</Link></li>
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Login</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    )
                  }
               </div>
         </Router>
      );
    }
}
  export default Navigation;
```

**SCSS Code:**

```
.NavbarContainer {
    border-bottom: 1px #E7E7E7 solid;
    .mobilecontainer {
        margin: 2.1em;
        .hamburger {
            display: inline;
            img {
                width: 35px;
                cursor: pointer;
                float: right;
            }
        }
    }

    .NavBar {
        // display: none;
        .RightNav {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 27px 0;
            border-right: none;
            border-left: none;
            border-bottom: 1px #E7E7E7 solid;
            font-size: large;
            a {
                color: #0E0E0E;
            }
        }

    }


    .Dropdown {
        float: none;
        overflow: hidden;

        .Dropdown-Content {
            position: relative;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 2;
            min-width: 217px;       
            a {
                float: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                border: 1px #E7E7E7 solid;
                padding: 15px 22px;
            }
        }
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        a {
            &:hover {
                 background-color:  #ddd
            }
        }
    }

    .dropdown {
        &:hover {
            .dropdown-content {
                display: block;
            }
        }
    }

    .LeftNav {
        flex-grow: 8.2;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: large;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    @media (min-width: 55em) {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding: 3em;
        .LeftNav {
            flex-grow: 0.2;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: large;
        }

        .mobilecontainer {
            margin: 0;
            .hamburger {
                img {
                    display: none
                }
            }
        }

        .NavBar {
            display: flex;
            .RightNav {
                padding-left: 15px;
                padding-right: 15px;
                text-align: initial;
                border-bottom: none;
                font-size: large;
            }

            .FarRight {
                flex-grow: 1;
            }
        }

        .Dropdown {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
            .Dropdown-Content {
                position: absolute;
                top: 96px;
                background-color: white;
                z-index: 2;
                min-width: 217px;       
                a {
                    text-align: left;
                    padding: 15px 22px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is SCSS code that I'm using for this project.

Comment: please add your CSS

Comment: @Alex I have just added the SCSS code for the project.

Answer (score 1):

`this.state.show` is responsible just for **toggle mobile menu**.when `show ===false` react ignore rendering navBar neither in mobile or desktop.you cant use this way for your goal.My suggestion is to consider using [react-bootstrap Navbar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) or [reactstrap Navbar](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navbar/)
I hope this will help you.